# Customizing some aspect of algorithmic environment

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

I'm using the `algorithmic` environment for typesetting algorithm in my document, but I'd like to customize some aspect and fix problems.

I'm using the `algpseudocode` package with `noend` option, but it produces an ugly vertical gap when the end lines are suppressed (see picture below between the sixth and the seventh lines). How can I fix this problem?

Second, I'm using `function` command to produce two distinct procedures in the same `algorithm` environment, but I'd like to have only the function body to be line-numbered and the line count should restart from 1 for the Reduce function.

Third and last, I've separated the two functions using the `\Statex` command, but I'd like to have a less vertical space width than a whole white line.

This is my code.

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Calcola il grado di ogni vertice del grafo $G = (V,E)$}
    \label{degree}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Function{\textsc{Map}$( \left \langle u;v \right \rangle )$}{}
            \State \textbf{emit} $\left \langle u;v \right \rangle$
        \EndFunction
        \Statex
        \Function{\textsc{Reduce}$( \left \langle u;\Gamma(u) \right \rangle )$}{}
            \State $d(u) \gets 0$
            \ForAll{$v \in \Gamma(u)$}
                \State $d(u) \gets d(u) + 1$
            \EndFor
            \State \textbf{emit} $\left \langle u;d(u) \right \rangle$
        \EndFunction
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Replace `\Statex` with `\medskip`, for instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To restart line numbering from 1, you have to reset the counter `ALG@line`, so we define a new command `\resetline` to be issued when you want that change:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\resetline}{\setcounter{ALG@line}{0}}
\makeatother
```

In regards of the spacing between two functions, you can use a normal skip instead of issuing a `\Statex` (`\smallskip`, `\medskip`, `\bigskip`).

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\resetline}{\setcounter{ALG@line}{0}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Calcola il grado di ogni vertice del grafo $G = (V,E)$}
    \label{degree}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Function{\textsc{Map}$( \left \langle u;v \right \rangle )$}{}
            \State \textbf{emit} $\left \langle u;v \right \rangle$
        \EndFunction
        \medskip\resetline
        \Function{\textsc{Reduce}$( \left \langle u;\Gamma(u) \right \rangle )$}{}
            \State $d(u) \gets 0$
            \ForAll{$v \in \Gamma(u)$}
                \State $d(u) \gets d(u) + 1$
            \EndFor
            \State \textbf{emit} $\left \langle u;d(u) \right \rangle$
        \EndFunction
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

The little gap related to the `noend` option is to indicate the end of the function, so I'll leave it as is, but if you really want to remove it, you can add these lines in your preamble (require the `etoolbox` package):

```
\patchcmd{\ALG@doentity}
  {\item[]\nointerlineskip}
  {\relax}
  {}
  {}
```

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\resetline}{\setcounter{ALG@line}{0}}
\patchcmd{\ALG@doentity}
  {\item[]\nointerlineskip}
  {\relax}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Calcola il grado di ogni vertice del grafo $G = (V,E)$}
    \label{degree}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Function{\textsc{Map}$( \left \langle u;v \right \rangle )$}{}
            \State \textbf{emit} $\left \langle u;v \right \rangle$
        \EndFunction
        \medskip\resetline
        \Function{\textsc{Reduce}$( \left \langle u;\Gamma(u) \right \rangle )$}{}
            \State $d(u) \gets 0$
            \ForAll{$v \in \Gamma(u)$}
                \State $d(u) \gets d(u) + 1$
            \EndFor
            \State \textbf{emit} $\left \langle u;d(u) \right \rangle$
        \EndFunction
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer! Since we both come from Italy, I appreciate it even much! ;)

Comment: @Driu Happy to help. And happy to discover that one more Italian person is over here. Ciao :-)